# How to link files to different/multiple repositories?

Tags: github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, tortoisegit

Let's say, I have project/repository folder (with it sub folders/files), example structure:

```
MyProject
 - Folder_1
 -- file_A   
 -- file_B
 - Folder_2
 -- file_C
 -- file_D
```

I have two needs:

1. I want to add another developer, who should access only:

```
MyProject
- Folder_1
-- file_A
- Folder_2
-- file_D
```

2. I need also, that I could link `Folder_2` to another repository. Is that possible that a folder were linked to multiple repos?

However, on my Windows (I use `TortoiseGit`), I am unable to achieve "multi-linked" repos idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for "another repository"

You can simply make a **[branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)** in the same repo, where you remove any elements you don't want, in order to leave only:

```
- Folder_1
-- file_A
- Folder_2
-- file_Deave only
```

Your developer can work in that branch of the same repository. 
See "[TortoiseGit Manual / Branching/Tagging](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-branchtag.html)"

```
TortoiseGit → Create Branch...
```

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/Branch.png]

---

> that I could link Folder_2 to another repository.

Then you can delete `Folder_2` (in that branch made for your developer), and declare your remote repo as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)** under the path Folder2.
See [TortoiseGit submodules](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-submodules.html).

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/GitSubModuleAdd.png]

Comment: thanks, how i couldnt thought that. however, i have modified question and if you can update answer to reflect the answer again, i will appreciate.

Comment: @T.Todua Sure. i have updated the answer accordingly.